# jquery plugin problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I`m trying to figure out how to properly create jquery plugin. Here is what I do

```
(function( $ ){

          $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
            console.log(this.eq(0).text());
          };
        })( jQuery ); 

$('#sector1').myPlugin();
```

Here is html

```
<div id="sector1">
        <span class="timestamp">1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="sector2">
        <span class="timestamp">2</span>
    </div>
```

The problem is that I can't get the text of sector1 span tag.
How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
    $.widget("ui.myplugin", {
        _init: function() {
            var text = $("#sector1 .timestamp", this.element).html();
        }

    });
})(jQuery);
```